# Refreshing the php output without realoading the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

The php script parses xml file and print output on page inside div:

```
<?php
$playlistUrl = 'http://url/to/playlist.xml';
$xmldata = file_get_contents($playlistUrl);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmldata);

foreach( $xml->trackList->track as $track ) {
    echo $track->title .' - '. $track->annotation .'<br>';
}
?>
```

I want to update the output every 25sec without reloading the page, using some AJAX method. I find some code samples that set time interval:

```
// Poll the server each 60 seconds
window.setInterval(function() 
}, 60000);
```

also

```
setInterval(function(){
SomeAjaxFunction();
}, 1000);
```

How to implement this properly in my case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out my answer here.

[Refresh page element after specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328427/refresh-page-element-after-specific-time/10328559#10328559)

i have answered about how to reload the div after specific time, you can tweak it a bit to keep reloading after a time interval.

the basics goes as follows.

```
<div id="reload">
//your PHP code and content are here.
</div>
```

and your jQuery code.

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
    $('#reload').fadeOut("slow").load('reponse.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: this works, thank you. The setInterval is a standard JavaScript function, not part of jQuery?

Comment: @fxgreen  it doesn't matter if it is a part of jQuery or not, coz jQuery itself is javascript. so it is absolutely ok to use native javascript in jQuery. BTW if it helped you then you can mark this as answered.

Comment: just to clear: where the script should go, in head or in body? There is also ~10sec delay after reloading page before output appears.

Comment: i prefer keeping the javascript code in head tag. if you place it in the head be sure to wrap the code in `$(document).ready(function(){ /**your jQuery code goes here**/ })`

Comment: about the ten second delay not sure what is causing it, unless i see your php code. post it as a new question and give me the link here. and also you should mark this as accepted if it helped you. that is the least you could do.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout executes the function after X seconds... then if you make it recursive you will always have X seconds to wait ***after*** the code has been executed. This is preferred over setInterval which executes exactly every X seconds.

Think about when the server is lagging and the load() takes a few seconds to actually load... well now the *animation* is half timed out and is doing to reload / fade again....

```
function loopy_function() {
    // ajax call
    // on success 
    setTimeout(loopy_function, 1000 * 10 );

}
```

The key here is to only call your setTimeout on a completed response.